# Best Practice to install a temporary QTranslator for subpart of QApplication

Tags: python, qt, pyside6, qt6

I use the following code to setup translation when setting up my PySide6 application:

```py
app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
translator_ui = QTranslator()
if translator_ui.load(f"lang_{config.language.ui}", "translations"):
    app.installTranslator(translator_ui)
```

Now I have the requirement that it should possible to export a pdf report, which is generated by the application should be exported in a different language as the application. So I marked all string in the report generator as translatable and continued.

After this I came up with the following solution for the "temporary language switch".

```py
existing_app = QApplication.instance()
if existing_app:

    existing_app.removeTranslator(translator_ui)
    translator_report = QTranslator()
    if translator_report.load(f"lang_{config.language.report}", "translations"):
        existing_app.installTranslator(translator_report)

    report.generate_document()
    report.save_document()

    translator_ui = QTranslator()
    if translator_ui.load(f"lang_{config.language.ui}", "translations"):
        existing_app.installTranslator(translator_ui)
```

This works fine, but I am not sure if this is a valid approach to switch the whole application translator just for generation of an report...

Comment: You should [remove the old translator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#removeTranslator).

Comment: See the Qt6 Docs: [Using Multiple Translations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtranslator.html#using-multiple-translations).

Comment: @ekhumoro Don't know why I was so blind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation, my approach seems to be the way to go:

> Multiple translation files can be installed in an application. Translations are searched for in the reverse order in which they were installed, so the most recently installed translation file is searched for translations first and the earliest translation file is searched last. The search stops as soon as a translation containing a matching string is found.

> This mechanism makes it possible for a specific translation to be "selected" or given priority over the others; simply uninstall the translator from the application by passing it to the QCoreApplication::removeTranslator() function and reinstall it with QCoreApplication::installTranslator(). It will then be the first translation to be searched for matching strings.

from [Using Multiple Translations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtranslator.html#using-multiple-translations)